# REST API: humanize errors for end users

Tags: rest, error-handling, documentation

Our system consists of REST API and ReactJS application. Some endpoints might return `4xx` status code with `message` field describing an error. The point is those error messages are rather generic and do not fit with UI/UX design requirements.

The frontend lead proposed to return additional status code as a message key (i.e. `err_code: ARTICLE_NAME_IS_NOT_UNIQUE`). In that case, ReactJS app might render the specific error message. We just need to keep track of possible error codes on a Wiki page.

I wonder is this a good approach? I'd like to declare the API so descriptive that you can get all required errors' information with Open API specification. We can try to assign each error for an individual `4xx` status code. Though I'm not sure this a right way to go because some errors on the same endpoint might have different error messages but be assigned to the same status code.

Also, we can return the formatted message as backend payload. But in this case, the server becomes dependent on UI/UX requirements (if error message has to be changed). We'd like to avoid that.

What are the best practices to handle REST API errors and humanize the output for end users? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Communicating responses is important but it can eventually become a burden. As your product expands the variations in responses tend to increase as well.

Utilizing [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is great practice. They serve as fundamental building block to lean on.

[The OpenApi 3.0 Documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) suggests reusing same response codes in the definition:

> If multiple operations return the same response (status code and data), you can define it in the global responses section and reference that definition via $ref at the operation level. This is useful for error responses with the same status codes and response body.

A common way to improve the default error messages and communicating the response to end users is to including custom error messages i.e. `userError` and `systemError` in the API body response.
For example errors in Microsoft Graph are returned using standard HTTP status codes, as well as a JSON error response object:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "badRequest",
    "message": "Uploaded fragment overlaps with existing data.",
    "innerError": {
      "code": "invalidRange",
      "request-id": "request-id",
      "date": "date-time"
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding your question about "whether to have a Wiki page for possible error codes", I believe establishing a parent-child relationship between the backend and the frontend is essential in order to keep track of different error messages. In your case the API should be responsible of generating the right error messages that the frontend can then interpret accordingly to the end user.

Here are some good read recommendations:

- [Microsoft REST API Guidelines: Error condition responses](https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#7102-error-condition-responses)
- [The Complete Guide to Status Codes for Meaningful ReST APIs (Lucas Santos 2020)](https://dev.to/_staticvoid/the-complete-guide-to-status-codes-for-meaningful-rest-apis-1-5c5)